# Using different certificate for one domain

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, ssl-certificate

I currently have Apache setup to use a certificate on all my domains using these settings in ssl.conf:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/mycert.crt
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/mykey.key
SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/digicert/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

I would like to use a different self-signed certificate for one domain/virtual host on the server.  I tried adding this to my httpd.conf file, but the old certificate is still being presented to the browser.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
        ServerName myotherdomain.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony/web
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/selfsigned.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/selfsigned.key
        SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/digicert/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Is there a way to set this up so that this one domain using a different certificate than the others?

Comment: Notice that using different certificates for name based virtual hosts require SNI support on the client. It is impossible to get it working for clients without SNI support.

Comment: @ericx Separate IPv4 addresses for every domain with SSL isn't going to be realistic forever. At some point web site operators will have to say sorry, we don't support clients running IPv4 without SNI. At that point users will have to switch to newer clients with SNI support or upgrade to IPv6. But this should of course be an informed decision made by the site owner. It should not be the result of an admin deploying certificates without knowing the difference between clients with and without SNI support.

Comment: If I am able to use a separate IP, would I be able to do this by amending the VirtualHost config like this? <VirtualHost 5.5.6.7:443>

Comment: I think that would work.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `NameVirtualHost *:443` prior to your `VirtualHost`:

```
NameVirtualHost *:443

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/mycert.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/mykey.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/digicert/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName myotherdomain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/symfony/web
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/httpd/conf/selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/selfsigned.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/httpd/conf/digicert/DigiCertCA.crt
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I already have NameVirtualHost *:443 earlier in my httpd.conf file

Comment: Requisites on apache: Use OpenSSL 0.9.8f or later. Build OpenSSL with the TLS Extensions option enabled (option enable-tlsext; OpenSSL 0.9.8k and later has this enabled by default).

Comment: I'm using CentOS and the latest version available is 0.9.8e-27.el5_10.3.  Does that mean that I cannot use multiple certificates on this server?

Comment: It seems like the <VirtualHost _default_:443> section of ssl.conf is overriding anything that I put in the VirtualHost blocks.  Is <VirtualHost _default_:443> even needed?

Comment: You could try it, but should not matter. It only applies if you had different IP and wanted to distinguish between them. The openssl issue limits you to support SNI on your apache. Could you upgrade your CentOS version?